# Get multiple tables data without performance lost?

Tags: mysql, performance

I got my table called `cars` , and the second table called `uploads` which has a `car_id` field, I can `LEFT JOIN` this, so the `uploads.car_id = cars.id`, the problem comes, and `uploads` table, for more than one record for certain car id, what then? I have to use second query **in a loop** like this?

```
$cars = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM `cars`")->fetchAll();
foreach($cars as $car)
{
    $uploads = $PDO->query("SELECT * from uploads WHERE id = " . (int)$car['id'])->fetch();
    echo 'My upload file name:' . $uploads['hash'];
}
```

? Its not a good idea, because `$cars` query may return more than 500 records at once... So it will be a huge performance lost.

So my question is, what can I do in this case, to prevent the query in the loop?

Comment: Can you explain the result you need. I don't understand sorry

Comment: @Marc, I want to access `hash` field in the `uploads` table for certain car.id, without doing a query for every single car id (in a loop).

Comment: @Scott see my answer below it get all values by one query :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the GROUP BY and GROUB_CONCAT sql functions to get what you want in one query with better performance

try :

```
$cars = $PDO->query("SELECT cars.id as carID, GROUP_CONCAT(hash) AS hashs FROM uploads left join cars on uploads.car_id = cars.id group by cars.id ")->fetchAll();

foreach($cars as $car)
{
   echo 'Car id '.$car['carID'].'  --  uploaded files name:' . $uploads['hashs'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not left join on uploads?

Use Explain to determine the results, in mysql what does:

`explain select * from cars left join uploads on cars.id = uploads.car_id where id=1;`

If you have indexes on cars.id and uploads.car_id, this should be a fast query.  Also turn on query caching and watch your stats to see if it is helping.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the left join:

```
select c.id, u.hash
from cars c
left join upload u on c.id = u.car_id;
```

When you have multiple `hash` values for a certain `car_id`, you will simply get multiple rows. Not really a problem.